# Criar array para validar CPF duplicado em um Laço de Repetição em PHP

Tags: php

Meu objetivo primário é `importar` dados de uma `planilha em Excel` para o `Mysql`  utilizando `PHP`.

Eu concluí este objetivo e já consigo importar todas as colunas do Excel para as respectivas `tabelas` do banco de dados!

Meu próximo objetivo é fazer uma espécie de `validação`!

Por exemplo!

Validar se `um mesmo CPF existe para dois clientes diferentes`.

Abaixo está um exemplo da planilha Excel!!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo tenho uma amostra da função que resulta as coluna e linhas da planilha!

```
private function import_file($file)
    {
        $path   = $file;
        $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);
            
        foreach($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
        {
            $highestRow    = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
            $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();
            
            $person_array_testing = [];
            for($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)
            {
                # array testing
                $cpf_cnpj = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
                $name     = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                $contract = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                $invoice  = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue();
                $document = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue();
                $value    = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue();
                $expiry   = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue();
                $address  = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue();
                $phone    = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue();
                $email    = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getValue();
                
                // print 1
                // pr($cpf_cnpj);
                // pr($name);
                
                if( ! empty($cpf_cnpj))
                {
                    $keys = [$cpf_cnpj];
                    $new_array = array_fill_keys($keys, $name);
                    // print 2
                    pr($new_array); 
                }                
                # array testing
            }
        }
    }
```

A minha idéia para validar CPF duplicado era criar um `array`, utilizando o CPF como `chave` e o nome do cliente como `valor`; depois iria validar se a `chave` do array se repete e, caso positivo, iria retornar false e interromper a importação.

Acredito que, no caso de um CPF duplicado, o array esperado fosse este;

```
[
    '11111111177' => 'MARIA DE LOURDES CAETANO',
    '11111111177' => 'ADRIENE FARIA MARTINS CONRADO DOS SANTOS'
]
```

Seguem imagens de como esta retornando, utilizando o `print_r` do `PHP`

print 1 e 2, conforme está no código da função, respectivamente
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Será que podem me ajudar a criar este array de forma correta ou me passarem alguma outra idéia para se fazer esta validaçao ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que pensou, não dará certo, pois nunca será possível colocar duas chaves iguais em uma array, com valores diferentes.

**EDIT**

Já que a ideia é apenas "**validar se um mesmo CPF existe para dois clientes diferentes**" e caso houver duplicatas, parar a importação, você pode fazer assim:

```
$cpfs = array();
for($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){
  $cpf_cnpj = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
  $name     = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
  if(array_key_exists($cpf_cnpj, $cpfs) && $cpfs[$cpf_cnpj] != $name){
    echo "CPF/CNPJ duplicado: " . $cpf_cnpj;
  }else{
    $cpfs[$cpf_cnpj] = $name;
  }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas existe alguma forma de saber(identificar) quem é duplicado?

Comment: E testando o código, percebi que esta retornando duplicado, mesmo quando não há duplicidade. Neste caso o CPF até pode existir em mais de uma linha, o que não pode  eh ter dois nomes diferentes com um mesmo CPF

Comment: Com quais valores você testou que deu duplicado, mesmo sem existirem?

Comment: Testei os dois valores que estão na imagem, na primeira imagem que contém o Excel

Comment: Que estranho, consegue mandar o resultado do `echo json_encode($cpfs);`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/MJ95FuE

Comment: Ahh sim, de fato, eu tinha entendido errado. Editei a resposta, agora deve ser o que espera.

Comment: Meu retorno agora é: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer ...

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109321/discussion-between-lucius-and-wagner-fillio).

Comment: Alterei o tipo de dados da variável `cpf_cnpj` e deu tudo certo, obrigado pela ajuda!!